# error: file to import not found or unreadable: "compass/reset"

Tags: rubygems, sass, compass-sass

I'm on OSX 10.6.8, running RubyGems 1.8, and Compass 0.12.2.

This is happening in all of my Compass projects at the moment, but even creating a simple test  project via Terminal -> "compass create myproject" gives me the following error...

error: file to import not found or unreadable: "compass/reset"

What can I do to even start bug fixing this?

Answer (score 0):

Suggestion from the team here is use: Ruby 1.9.3, compass 1.0.0, sass 3.3.3
There was some issues with earlier version of sass/compass, but we have the set-up running for us... we're following the workflow from the @kitt talk at DrupalSouth if you want to compare notes elsewhere!

Comment: I have rvm installed but not really sure how to use it! :/

Comment: rvm install 1.9.3

Error running 'requirements_osx_brew_update_system ruby-1.9.3-p545',
showing last 15 lines of /Users/brock/.rvm/log/1395641773_ruby-1.9.3-p545/update_system.log
    https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/wiki/Common-Issues
and make sure `brew update` works before continuing.'

Not sure where to go from here? Tricky.

Comment: It seems OSX 10.6 is the issue...

    localhost:~ brock$ rvm install 1.9.3

Searching for binary rubies, this might take some time.
No binary rubies available for: osx/10.6/i386/ruby-1.9.3-p545.
Continuing with compilation. Please read 'rvm help mount' to get more information on binary rubies.
Checking requirements for osx.
Installing requirements for osx.
Updating system........................
Error running 'requirements_osx_brew_update_system ruby-1.9.3-p545',
showing last 15 lines of /Users/brock/.rvm/log/1395723091_ruby-1.9.3-p545/update_system.log

Comment: compass 1.0.0 not exist. The production version for now is 0.12.2

Answer (score -1):

I'm on Ubuntu - Virtual Machine (Windows) and use ruby 2.0.0, rails 4.1.0 and I also have this error. My solving problem is:

---

Don’t put the gem declaration in the assets group of your Gemfile!

(https://lessaccounting.com/blog/sass-compass-rails-4/)

If you're planning on using Sass, then you'll want to rename application.css to application.css.scss.

Delete the directives that are placed inside of comments called require, require_tree, and require_self.(https://github.com/rails/sass-rails)

That file should then look like:

@import "compass/reset";
@import "compass/css3";
@import    "compass/css3/images";

...your file (following http://thesassway.com/beginner/how-to-structure-a-sass-project)
for example:

@import "apps/header";
@import "apps/footer";